# Dynamically compare version numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, version

I want to compare between different versions in MySQL like so:

```
select * from version_table where version > 5.2.9
```

while the column `version` can have values like 5.2.8, 5.2.11, 5.2.9.2, 5.3

currently the `select` that is written above does not return rows with the value '5.2.11'

I saw alot of solutions that statically compare between versions that all of the versions have the same structure for exmaple X.XX or X.XX.XX but what if all my versions have different structures and vary between X.XX, X.XX.XX and X.XX.XX.XX?

Comment: Reference string literal must be quoted. String value must be converted to solid form with zero-padding (5.2.9 => 5020900).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL query - compare version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876711/mysql-query-compare-version-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you compare `VARCHAR` data type, not `INT`.

When you compare numeric data types, 9 is less than 11.
But when you compare in, I will say, strings data types then it will not be the case. Because `5.2.` is same in every case it will compare again 9 and 11, so basically it will compare the first character which means it compares 9 and 1. As you guess 1 it is less than 9 and if you try `where version < 5.2.9` it will give you `5.2.11`

Note: with this `where` query is not correct by real logic.

Maybe solution to split into more columns like `major version`, `minor version`, `build version` and `revision` or whatever you want to name it